# Loop remove files from folder which has some special text inside file

Tags: python, loops, os.path

I have folder with many .txt files. I want to remove files from this folder which have words 'Best Regards' inside file.
I wrote simple loop but I still have problem `I/O operation on closed file`.

Here is my code.

```
import os, os.path
path = 'H:/UsersData/...'

for f in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path, f), encoding = 'utf-8') as input_data:
        for line in input_data:
            if 'Best Regards' in line:
                input_data.close()
                os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
```

Comment: I added continue to the end of if, but it only removed one file, and the error still exits

Comment: My bad, its `break` not `continue`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a check flag.

**EX:**

```
import os, os.path
path = 'H:/UsersData/...'

deleteFile = False
for f in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path, f), encoding = 'utf-8') as input_data:
        for line in input_data:
            if 'Best Regards' in line:
                deleteFile = True
                break
    if deleteFile:
        os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
        deleteFile = False
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to break the for loop when you find the line containing 'Best Regards'. As you are using a context manager, there is no need to explicitly close the file. The file will be closed when the context manager exits. Then you can delete the file

```
import os, os.path
path = 'H:/UsersData/...'

for f in os.listdir(path):
    delete_file = False
    with open(os.path.join(path, f), encoding = 'utf-8') as input_data:
        for line in input_data:
            if 'Best Regards' in line:
                delete_file = True
                break
     if delete_file:
         os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
```

Comment: And what will happens if the expression not found? your are still delete the file anyway...

Comment: And now your answer is pretty much like @Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

Get used to using pathlib.  Also you want to make sure you want to delete the files,  you do that by building up a list of files you want to delete first (reviewing them to make sure the logic of the statement is correct) then axing them.  [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('H:/UsersData/...')
files_to_delete = [f for f in path.iterdir() if f.is_file() and 'Best Regards' in f.read_text()]
for f in files_to_delete:
    f.unlink()
```